# mass assignment selecting childs of user, using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form, mass-assignment

I have a very simple issue:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable 

  attr_accessible :id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
    :firstname, :lastname, :mobile_phone, :user_type, :department_id, :department_attributes

  belongs_to :department

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :department, :allow_destroy => false
```

Departments model:

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :allow_destroy => true
```

I created a form to be able to select my departments member from my existing users using simple_form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @department, :validate => true  do |form| %>

    <%= form.error_messages %>
    <%= form.association :users, :prompt => 'assign a user', :label => 'User'%>
    <%= form.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

Then I (try to) update my users via the department controller:

```
  def update
    @department = Department.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @department.update_attributes(params[:department])
      ...
```

This generates following error:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_ids
```

My guess is that some devise settings generate this error but I don't know which ones.

Can you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `attr_accessible :user_ids` to your Department model.

Comment: Wouaw, that does the trick! I'd been blocked for two hours looking for a reason in users rather than in departments. Many many thanks!